# jquery change background on click

Tags: jquery, click, hover

I have a table list for my records and I use a hover function to change the backgroundcolor to blue. For that everyting works fine.

No i added a click function for changing the backgroundcolor to yellow but for some reason the background turns into blue (the same color for the hover function).

I made a demo for a better example which you can find [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/KuwWs/).

I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: Why have you got multiple tables pretending to be one table?

Answer (score 5):

This is because you have two backgrounds specified at the time your mouse is hovering over the row and clicking on it. You need to specify which one is more **important**.

Try to change table_record_selected to this:

background:#FFFBCC !important;

Answer (score 1):

use !important:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/KuwWs/8/

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a class for the hovering so you can toggle it the same way you toggle the class when the row is clicked.

In the CSS code :

```
.table_record_hover
{
    background-color: #EBF3F6;  
}
```

In the JS code :

```
$('table.table_record_even').click(function()
{
    $(this).toggleClass('table_record_hover');
    $(this).toggleClass('table_record_selected');
});

$('table.table_record').click(function()
{
    $(this).toggleClass('table_record_hover');
    $(this).toggleClass('table_record_selected');
});



$('table.table_record').hover(function()
{
    if($(this).hasClass('table_record_selected'))
    {
    }
    else
    {
         $(this).toggleClass('table_record_hover');
    }
},

function()
{
    if($(this).hasClass('table_record_selected'))
    {
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).toggleClass('table_record_hover');
    }
});

$('table.table_record_even').hover(function()
{
    if($(this).hasClass('table_record_selected'))
    {
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).toggleClass('table_record_hover');
    }
},

function()
{
    if($(this).hasClass('table_record_selected'))
    {
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).toggleClass('table_record_hover');
    }
});
```

This way the row does not have the two styles at the same time.